# What does it mean when a field of mathematics has 'differential' in its name?

Tags: soft-question

Topology and geometry, for example, have their 'differential counterparts' (as well as 'algebraic'). What is required of a mathematical discipline for there to exist such a subfield? For example, why isn't 'differential knot theory' a thing?

Comment: For the last: Because knots are inherently discrete

Comment: So a 'prerequisite', if you will, is that the structures be continuous and/or non-discrete?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen: does this preclude knot theory from being the subject of the "calculus of finite differences"?